# Unable to resolve 'Class is not key value coding-compliant'

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uilabel

I created a class with XIB file and an UILabel in it, using Interface Builder. The UILabel was linked with an IBOutlet in the corresponding .h class.
I deleted the XIB file, but I now get the following error message upon execution:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ChildViewController 0x91d9340> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key <IBOutletName for Label>.'
```

I tried to clean the project, delete all references to this IBOutletName in the project, tried to find this name with Grep in the code, but still have the issue. Any idea where I can find this name and delete it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find where the name is used, first type the outlet back into the code. If Xcode determines that there is a connection for that outlet, it will fill in the circle in the left margin. Click on the circle, and you should see something like this

[image]

For future reference, you should always delete all connections in the xib or storyboard, before deleting the corresponding IBOutlets/IBActions from the code.  To do this,

- open the xib
- select the File's Owner
- open the Connections inspector
- delete all the connections

Then go to the source code, and verify that none of the corresponding IBOutlets/IBActions have filled circles in the left margin.

[image]

---

If the problem persists, it may help to delete the build directory, and delete the app from the device.

To delete the build directory

- open Xcode (but don't open the project)
- in the `Window` menu, select `Organizer`
- select `Projects` at the top of the organizer window
- right click on the project name in the list at the left
- select `Remove from Organizer...` from the popup menu
- click `Delete`

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I proceeded as suggested, removed the connection from the File Owner, and finally removed the IBOutlet from the .h file and both XIBs -> Same error. I have to leave the IBOutlet in the .h file (empty circle on its left) to avoid the crash. Any idea where this could come from ? Thanks.

Comment: @LaurentCrivello  I'm afraid I don't know. The only suggestion I have is to clean the project and delete the app from the device, and then try again. I've added a clean procedure to my answer.

Comment: The procedure you added works perfectly if succeeded by a Project Clean. Thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is maybe some bug that occurs sometimes. For me nothing helped because I had everything right in xib, but after I clean and uninstalled app from device everything worked again. So don't know if clean or uninstall but both helped.